# GeoServer - Can't find a response parser factory for GET_FEATURE/'text/html'

Tags: geoserver, getfeature

I am rerouting my GetFeature-Request using a Proxy-Script. The Script is returning the feature collection as an xml but I can not see them when using the layer-preview and get an error:

```
Can't find a response parser factory for GET_FEATURE/'text/html'
```

I am using geoserver 2.14 and I am not sure if the format I am returning is correct? Or if there is something else missing/wrong.

What does Geoserver expect as response for getFeature-Requests?

Comment: `application/gml`  probably

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm now!

Answer (score 1):

As @Ian Turton mentioned in his comment, Geoserver expects a valid application/gml as an repsonse for the GetFeature-request, editing my PHP-Script to echo with content-type application/gml

```
   header("Content-type: application/gml");
```

made it work.